# ASP.NET - TTL on Session Key-Value-Pairs (InProc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Is there a sanctioned method for adding TTL to ASP.NET InProc Session State entries?

**Example:**

```
Session("First", 60) = "John"
Session("Adams", 500) = "Adams"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, no there isn't. Individual Session State Key-Value-Pairs do not have any built-in method for adding a TTL or TTE.

Regarding the "global" InProc session state-timeout, it is controlled by a session state wide value configured in your `web.config` file (the `timeout` value in the `/system.web/sessionState` settings).

Additionally, whilst it may look like an attractive proposition to create your own session state provider, you couldn't use the `Session` property exposed by the page or controller code as this returns a `HttpSessionState` object. None of the methods, properties or indexers support having an extra parameter to specify individual session value timeouts.

**You may consider doing the following:**

- Maintain an active session for each user:

  Session("PersistMe") = true
- Grab SessionID, and use it to store values in the ASP.NET Cache where you may utilize a TTL value.

Comment: Thanks, I will just make sure the Session stays live (by storing SOMETHING in the session), and then using the SessionID in the ASP.NET Cache where TTL works.